# Visualforce List Action keep reloading

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, list-view, bulk

Hi I created a custom List view button with `Visualforce`. The intension of the custom button is to support bulk approve. Expected behaviour is, when an user press the button, it should load `visualforce` page and then `onload` it calls an `apex action function`. Then `oncomplete` it should return to the previous page(the list view).

But, when an user logged in and press the button, it keeps loading the visulforce page itself. If the user go back to the list view again, and click the button again, it works fine. The issue happens only in the first click of the user's session.

I'm new to visualforce. Appreciate any help or hint. Please see the related code below.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" extensions="CustomObjectBulkApproval" recordSetVar="customObjectRecords" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="approve" action="{!approveActionFunction}" oncomplete="redirectToListView();" />
    </apex:form>
 
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() { 
            console.log('window.onload');
            approve();
        };
  
        function redirectToListView(){
            console.log('going back');
            sforce.one.back(true); 
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**CustomObjectBulkApproval apex class**

```
public class CustomObjectBulkApproval {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    String errorOnSubmit;

    public ParticipantActivityBulkApproval(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void approveActionFunction(){
        return; // do nothing at the moment
    }
}
```

Also please see the `console` output first time when the user click the button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resolve the issue with `apex:actionFunction`. Instead calling the same method as an `action` of the `visualforce page` worked for me. Following is the updated code.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" extensions="CustomObjectBulkApproval" recordSetVar="customObjectRecords" action="{!approveActionFunction}">
</apex:page>
```

**CustomObjectBulkApproval apex class**

```
public class CustomObjectBulkApproval {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;

    public ParticipantActivityBulkApproval(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void approveActionFunction(){
        return new ApexPages.Action('{!list}').invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use window.onload, instead use a modern event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('load',approve);
```

If you override window.onload, weird things can happen.

Second, without a `rerender` attribute, the page will reload, potentially causing an infinite loop:

```
<apex:actionFunction rerender="" name="approve" action="{!approveActionFunction}" oncomplete="redirectToListView();" />
```

Make sure you're not reloading the page automatically.

Comment: I tried adding event Listener and rerender as well. But still `force.one.back(true)` loads the same page, and continues. What is strange is this happens only when you click the button first time. If you navigate to list view and click the button again, it works fine.

Comment: @IsuruBuddhikaHerath Maybe there's an intermediate page load? Have you checked the network logs on your browser to check?